# In node.js, how do I run a .bat file in new window?

Tags: node.js, batch-file, exec

I have a node.js script on windows 10. I need to launch a `.bat` file so that it runs **in its own window**, with working directory set to its location. I've looked at a ton of options for `execSync` and `spawnSync`, but all of them seem to launch a headless child process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, so not sure of the intentions of your script, nor am I aware of the script layout in itself, so I am assuming you are at a point where you have nothing yet, so here is an example, in this case called `test.bat` where we `start` a new terminal window for `cmd` with the `/c` switch to close when completed.

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');
exec("start cmd /c test.bat", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
 if (err) {
   console.error(err);
   return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
 }
);
```

Comment: Thank you. The option the finally ended up working for me looked like ```childeProcess.exec(`start /D "${batFileFolder}"` cmd /k "${batFileFullPath}", callbackFn);```

Comment: @gerhard how can I run next line of script after this and want to wait for this process to done